# rich hotkey to replace a4j:commandButton

Tags: richfaces, hotkeys

I want to replace the a4j:commandButton or link with rich hotkey.Hotkey to enable/disable the rich tooltip . Any help would be appreciated.I am using rich face 4 so the handler attribute is not present in rich hotkey

The Piece of code is given below.

```
    <a4j:commandButton id="button1" action="#{bean.showTooltip()}" 
         value="Show Tooltip" render="staIns1"></a4j:commandButton>
    <rich:panel id="staIns1" styleClass="tooltip-text" style="border:0; background:none">
        <h:inputText id="a" value="#{bean.value}" style="width: 100%"></h:inputText>
        <rich:tooltip followMouse="false" showDelay="1500" 
            rendered="#{bean.showPanel}" id="staInsTt1" styleClass="tooltip"
            layout="block" style="width:200px;font-style:italic">

            <h:outputLabel value="#{bean.property1}" />

        </rich:tooltip>
    </rich:panel>
```

Comment: By handler I assume you mean the `@action` of the button, what does `bean.showToolTip()` do? Seems unnecessary to call the bean if you only want to show the tooltip.

Comment: i meant handler attribute of rich hotkey.<rich:hotkey handler="">                 bean.showToolTip() toggles the tooltip on /off which i want to do with rich hotkey(toggling the tooltip on/off with the hotkey)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<rich:hotkey>` in RF4 has `onkeyup` and `onkeydown` instead of `handler`.

To show the tooltip you can just do `onkeydown="#{rich:component('staInsTt1')}.show()"`, you don't have to call the bean.